# Numerically Solving a system of PDE (2 unknown functions)

Tags: differential-equations, numerical-integration, numerics, finite-element-method, boundary-conditions

I need to solve for function `H[x,y]` and `V[x,y]` on square `{x,0,1},{y,0,1}`, obeying the following PDEs and boundary conditions:
[image]

wherein $\rho_0(x,y)$ is simply defined as `1-x-y`, and $\sigma(t)=tanh(t)$ is the sigmoid function.

I use the following code to `NDSolve` it

```
rho0[x_, y_] := 1 - x - y
sigmoid[x_] := Tanh[x]
sol = NDSolve[{D[sigmoid[H[x, y]], y] == D[sigmoid[V[x, y]], x],
    D[H[x, y], x] + D[V[x, y], y] == rho0[x, y],
    H[0, y] == H[1, y] == V[x, 0] == V[x, 1] == 0},
    {H, V}, {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}]
```

but it produces no solution:

[image]
[image]

However, this simple instance actually has an analytical solution: $H(x,y)=F(x)$ and $V(x,y)=F(y)$ where $F(t) := (t - t^2)/2$. (This solution is very likely the unique one.) I'm wondering why the numerical solver gets nowhere near this theoretical solution.

The ultimate goal is to solve the system given more nested (but smooth at least) $\rho_0$'s. (An exogenous condition for $\rho_0$ is $\int_0^1 \int_0^1 \rho_0(x,y)dxdy=0$.) But I get stuck with the result above.

Any help appreciated! Thanks in advance.

Mathematica Version 12.0.0 student.

Comment: fyi, Tried it on Maple. It gives gives `pdsolve([pde1,pde2,bc],[H(x,y),V(x,y)])` $$
 \left\{ H \left( x,y \right) =-{\frac {{x}^{2}}{2}}+{\frac {x}{2}},V
 \left( x,y \right) =-{\frac {{y}^{2}}{2}}+{\frac {y}{2}} \right\}
$$ current version of Mathematica `DSolve` can not solve this analytically. Hopefully V 12.2 it will.

Comment: full Maple code of the above if someone is interested `restart;
rho0:= (x,y)->1 - x - y;
sigmoid:= x->tanh(x);
pde1 := diff(sigmoid(H(x, y)), y) = diff(sigmoid(V(x, y)), x);
pde2 := diff(H(x, y), x) + diff(V(x, y), y) = rho0(x, y);
bc := H(0, y) = 0, H(1, y) = 0, V(x, 0) = 0, V(x, 1) = 0;
pdsolve([pde1,pde2,bc],[H(x,y),V(x,y)])`

Answer (score 4):

This is an extended comment rather than an answer.  Results are for version 12.1.0 for Microsoft Windows (64-bit) (March 14, 2020).

`NDSolve` attempts to solve this system of PDEs by `Method -> "FiniteElement"`, and I surmise that it does so by linearizing the nonlinear terms in the PDEs about some initial guess and then repeating the process until the solution converges, using `FindRoot` with `Method -> "AffineCovariantNewton"`. The initial guess can be specified using the option `InitialSeeding`, and the symbolic solution given in the question should be a good initial guess.

```
sol = NDSolve[{D[sigmoid[H[x, y]], y] == D[sigmoid[V[x, y]], x], 
    D[H[x, y], x] + D[V[x, y], y] == rho0[x, y], 
    H[0, y] == H[1, y] == V[x, 0] == V[x, 1] == 0}, {H, V}, {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}, 
    InitialSeeding -> {H[x, y] == (x - x^2)/2, V[x, y] == (y - y^2)/2}] // Flatten
```

`NDSolve` twice returns the warning message

> > NDSolve`FEM`InitializePDECoefficients::femcscd: The PDE is convection dominated and the result may not be stable. Adding artificial diffusion may help.

but then returns the correct answer, as can be determined from

```
Plot3D[Evaluate[(D[sigmoid[H[x, y]], y] - D[sigmoid[V[x, y]], x]) /. sol], {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}]
Plot3D[Evaluate[(D[H[x, y], x] + D[V[x, y], y] - rho0[x, y]) /. sol], {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}]
```

which display noise with amplitudes of order `5 10^-15`.  Unfortunately, providing an initial guess differing only slightly from that given above

```
InitialSeeding -> {H[x, y] == (x - x^2)/2.01, V[x, y] == (y - y^2)/2.01}
```

yields the additional, undocumented error message

> > FindRoot::stfail: The method AffineCovariantNewton failed to compute the next step.

The resulting solution again gives noise for the first plot, but for the second plot gives the surprisingly smooth

[image]

Increasing resolution with

```
Method -> {"FiniteElement", "MeshOptions" -> {"MaxCellMeasure" -> .00001}}
```

is slower and returns essentially the same results.  I also tried running

```
SetOptions[FindRoot, Method -> {"AffineCovariantNewton", "BroydenUpdates" -> False}]
```

before `NDSolve`, which [documentation](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/UnconstrainedOptimizationMethodsForSolvingNonlinearEquations.html#45025331) suggested could improve accuracy.  Instead, `NDSolve` produced numerous error messages before returning unevaluated.  I also tried

```
SetOptions[FindRoot, Method -> "Newton"]
```

but after about 30 minutes without an answer I terminated the calculation.  Perhaps, other readers will find my unsuccessful attempts useful in exploring this deceptively simple question.