# Problem with NDSolve for 1st order non-linear system of PDEs

Tags: differential-equations, numerical-integration, finite-element-method

I wish to solve the PDE system

\begin{align}
x_u^2+y_u^2+\left(xx_u+yy_u \right)^2&=1\\
x_v^2+y_v^2+\left(xx_v+yy_v \right)^2&=1
\end{align}

subjected to $x(0,v)=0$ and $y(u,0)=0$. However, when using

```
eq1 = D[x[u, v], u]^2 + D[y[u, v], u]^2 + (x[u, v]*D[x[u, v], u] + y[u, v]*D[y[u, v], u])^2 == 1
eq2 = D[x[u, v], v]^2 + D[y[u, v], v]^2 + (x[u, v]*D[x[u, v], v] + y[u, v]*D[y[u, v], v])^2 == 1
bc = {x[0, v] == 0, y[u, 0] == 0}; 
sol = NDSolve[{{eq1, eq2}, bc}, {x, y}, {u, 0, 1}, {v, 0, 1}];
```

I get instead of a solution just a bunch of warnings, including `NDSolveFEM InitializePDECoefficients` and `FindRoot::stfail: The method AffineCovariantNewton failed to compute the next step.`  Any ideas about how to solve it ?

Comment: There is at least one typo: You haven't squared the last term that appears on the left-hand-side of the equations.

Comment: **I get instead of a solution just a bunch of warnings** this is strange. Using V 13.1 it does give solutions, but they are both zero when plotted. I see the warnings, but you say you get no solution? Screen shot (fixed your ode to add ^2)  ![Mathematica graphics](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZeWEq.png)  so for the warnings issue, then need to play with options to get try to get rid of them. There are few questions on this site with similar warnings and some workaround for them to try,  Here is one such example ..

Comment: ..  https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/220477/numerically-solving-a-system-of-pde-2-unknown-functions

Comment: @Nasser - with v13.1 on my Mac I don't get an answer just warning messages.

Comment: I am using windows. This is strange. I did not think the OS version would make difference.

Comment: @BobHanlon, do you have an ARM Mac?

Comment: @user21 - Mac OS X x86 (64-bit)

Comment: @BobHanlon, thanks. ARM macs currently do not play well with nonlinear FEM, because that makes use of MKL (intel) Pardiso solver, which is not available on the ARM architecture. But that does not seem to be the issue here. What does it do then, does it return unevaluated?

Comment: @user21 - It was just blank after the warnings; however, it appears to be an intermittent problem, just now it returned two `InterpolatingFunction` objects. But the functions evaluate to `{{0., 0.}}` for random values of `u` and `v`

Comment: @BobHanlon, If the blank return is something that is halfway reproducible, could you send it to the support please? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is exact solution to this problem. First, let put $x=x(u), y=y(v)$, then we can use `DSolve` as follows

```
DSolve[{D[x[u], u]^2+(x[u]*D[x[u], u])^2==1, x[0] == 0}, x, u]
(*{{x -> Function[{u}, 
    InverseFunction[
      1/2 (ArcTanh[#1/Sqrt[1 + #1^2]] + #1 Sqrt[
           1 + #1^2]) &][-u]]}, {x -> 
   Function[{u}, 
    InverseFunction[
      1/2 (ArcTanh[#1/Sqrt[1 + #1^2]] + #1 Sqrt[1 + #1^2]) &][u]]}}*)
```

Similar solution we have for $y(v)$. We can plot solutions as follows

```
lst = Table[{u, 
    Evaluate[
     InverseFunction[
       1/2 (ArcTanh[#1/Sqrt[1 + #1^2]] + #1 Sqrt[1 + #1^2]) &][
      u]]}, {u, 0, 1, .01}];

f = Interpolation[lst]; 
{Plot3D[f[u], {u, 0, 1}, {v, 0, 1}, Exclusions -> None, 
  AxesLabel -> Automatic, PlotLabel -> "x", 
  ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", PlotTheme -> "Marketing", 
  MeshStyle -> White], 
 Plot3D[f[v], {u, 0, 1}, {v, 0, 1}, Exclusions -> None, 
  AxesLabel -> Automatic, PlotLabel -> "y", 
  ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", PlotTheme -> "Marketing", 
  MeshStyle -> White]}
```

[image: Figure 1]

Please, pay attention that there are 4 solutions in combination of signs `x[u], y[v]`. It is why numerical solution not unique, and therefore we have a problem with computation. Second solution
[image: Figure 2]
Third solution
[image: Figure 3]
Fourth solution
[image: Figure 4]

We can solve this system with Matematica FEM using special regularization as follows

```
ClearAll["Global`*"]
Needs["NDSolve`FEM`"]

reg = Rectangle[{0, 0}, {1, 1}]; mesh = 
 ToElementMesh[reg, MaxCellMeasure -> .001]

eq1 = Inactivate[
   d1 Laplacian[x[u, v], {u, v}] + D[x[u, v], u]^2 + 
    D[y[u, v], 
      u]^2 + (x[u, v]*D[x[u, v], u] + y[u, v]*D[y[u, v], u])^2, 
   D | Laplacian];
eq2 = Inactivate[
   d2 Laplacian[y[u, v], {u, v}] + D[x[u, v], v]^2 + 
    D[y[u, v], 
      v]^2 + (x[u, v]*D[x[u, v], v] + y[u, v]*D[y[u, v], v])^2, 
   D | Laplacian];
bc = {DirichletCondition[x[u, v] == 0, u == 0], 
   DirichletCondition[y[u, v] == 0, v == 0]};


sol = NDSolve[{Activate[eq1] == 1, Activate[eq2] == 1, 
     bc} /. {d1 -> 10^-3, d2 -> 10^-3}, {x, y}, 
   Element[{u, v}, mesh]];
```

Visualization

```
{Plot3D[x[u, v] /. sol[[1]], {u, 0, 1}, {v, 0, 1}, Exclusions -> None,
   AxesLabel -> Automatic, PlotLabel -> "x", 
  ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", PlotTheme -> "Marketing", 
  MeshStyle -> White], 
 Plot3D[y[u, v] /. sol[[1]], {u, 0, 1}, {v, 0, 1}, Exclusions -> None,
   AxesLabel -> Automatic, PlotLabel -> "y", 
  ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", PlotTheme -> "Marketing", 
  MeshStyle -> White]}
```

[image: Figure 5]
Compare to analytical solution this is second case shown in Figure 2. To compute all cases, we change a sign of `d1,d2`, for instance, first and fourth solution are given by

```
sol1 = NDSolve[{Activate[eq1] == 1, Activate[eq2] == 1, 
     bc} /. {d1 -> -10^-3, d2 -> -10^-3}, {x, y}, 
   Element[{u, v}, mesh]];
sol4 = NDSolve[{Activate[eq1] == 1, Activate[eq2] == 1, 
     bc} /. {d1 -> 10^-3, d2 -> -10^-3}, {x, y}, 
   Element[{u, v}, mesh]];
```

Comment: Thank you. I knew the exact solution, but I am trying to understand the numerical problem to be able to use it in more complicated cases. I thus chose this one which would allow me to compare the exact and numerical results.

Comment: @DanielCastro The problem stated above in my answer. There is no unique solution, therefore any numerical method for nonlinear PDEs based on the Newton iterative method will compute several roots. As result solution does not converge.  We can try numerical optimization with constrains like $x(u,v)\ge 0, y(u,v)\ge 0$.

Comment: Is there a way to impose those constraints in `NDSolve` ?

Comment: @DanielCastro Please, see update to my answer.